# Django Queryset - How do I do math on related models with prefetch_related?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I have three models:

```
class Variety(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24)

class Item(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    in_stock = models.IntegerField()

class ItemPart(models.Model)        
    variety = models.ForeignKey(Variety)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to tell how much of each Variety has been made into Items by getting all the related ItemParts and multiplying their `qty` by the `in_stock` of their related Items.

I've gotten this far:

```
Variety.objects.all().prefetch_related('itempart_set').values('name').annotate(
    Sum(F("itempart_set__qty") * F("itempart_set__item_set__in_stock")
)
```

Will this work? Will it sum the products, or will it simply multiply the sums?

Comment: "Will this work?" Have you _tried it_? Surely that would have been easier than asking a question on Stack Overflow…

Comment: Well, I am trying to design my models correctly. So I would have to build them out, put in a bunch of fake data and try it. I was hoping someone could confirm before I go to the trouble of building them wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do math with models queried by `prefetch_related` because `prefetch_related` hits the database separately from the original query. Your queryset is probably evaluated to two database queries and math on the database level is out of the question in that case.

Now, I'm not saying that the above query won't work (Django works its magic and after all, we don't know which version you're using), but I'm saying that the `prefetch_related` will not give you a performance boost for calculating.

If the above does not work, I would try to do it with subqueries introduced in Django 1.11.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I wanted to know.

Comment: @AdamStarrh If that's what you wanted to know, then perhaps mark it as the correct answer as well?

Comment: Thought I had clicked that. Thanks for the catch